# Which driver does Karate UI test automation framework use in backend to connect with web browsers?

Tags: user-interface, automated-tests, webdriver, karate, testautomationfx

I am trying to understand that which web driver does karate UI test framework use to interact with web browsers. As its counterpart Selenium which is already a web driver is used for UI automation and testing. So how is karate different from Selenium?

Answer (score 1):

Karate uses Chrome directly by default. So no driver is required.

But Karate also is compatible with the [WebDriver W3C Specification](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/). This means that Karate can "talk" to any compatible driver, I guess you are familiar with chomedriver, geckodriver etc. The interesting thing is Karate does not depend on Selenium to do this, i.e. the WebDriver support is created from scratch in Karate. Teams have reported that Karate UI tests are more stable, and the whole ["wait" business](https://www.karatelabs.io/learning/the-karate-advantage-5-compelling-reasons-to-switch-from-selenium-for-test-automation) is much simpler.

Karate of course allows you to mix API testing and UI testing in the same flow.